# Override UP button in action bar

Tags: android, destroy

i'd like to avoid parent activity being destroyed whenever i clicked < button in action bar.

which method is being called from AppCompatActivity when we press that button?

is there a way for me to override it? and is there a way to override for all activities?

Answer (score 15):

> i'd like to avoid parent activity being destroyed whenever i clicked < button in action bar.

Your parent activity will be paused once you press that button, instead of gets destroyed.

> is there a way for me to override it? and is there a way to override for all activities?

Just call:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

You need to call it to activities you want to override the button. There's no other option to call it 'once for all'.

> which method is being called from AppCompatActivity when we press that button?

By default, there's no method in it. If you use `Toolbar`, call `setNavigationOnClickListener()` to do something when that button is pressed.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something here, such as start an Intent to the parent activity.
        }
    });
```

If you use `ActionBar`, that button will be available on `Menu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        // do something here, such as start an Intent to the parent activity.
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: If you set the click listener on the toolbar, it will no longer return to the parent unless you call something equivalent to `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask` in the listener.

Answer (score 12):

For those who are searching to override the up button to be the same as the back button and navigate from activity to another correctly, simply override

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home){
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```